# How to make a label of a shiny widget the same as plain text?

Tags: r, shiny, rshiny

In the following example, I have a numeric input. The font type of the label is bold (see the image). How can I make the font of the label as the same as plain text, like the one in "Here are some texts"?

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  br(),
  "Here are some texts",
  br(),
  numericInput(inputId = "num1",
               label = "This is a numeric input",
               value = NA)
)

server <- function(input, output){
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Adding this line to your `ui` will remove the bold from labels:

```
tags$head(tags$style(HTML("label {font-weight:normal;}"))),
```

[image]

---

Added, we can wrap it in a div and give it a class:

```
tags$head(tags$style(HTML(".not_bold label {font-weight:normal;}"))),
    div(numericInput(inputId = "num1",
                 label = "This is a numeric input",
                 value = NA),class="not_bold")  
    ,numericInput(inputId = "num2",
                 label = "This is a numeric input too",
                 value = NA)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the nice solution. I have upvoted your answer. I should have been more clear. There are other shiny widgets in my real-world example. For some reasons, I have to make the label of this one plain text. Your solution seems to make all labels plain. Would it be possible to just make a specific Shiny widget's label plain?

Comment: I have added to the answer to show how to change only the font-weight of a single class' labels